# How to make an hypertext link on a list that contains "material-icons"?

Tags: html, css, list, href, google-material-icons

I want to develop a floating bar that contains icons (material-icons). Unfortunately, my `<a href=>` attribute doesn't work and the icons are not clickable.

Any idea how to solve this?

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<ul id="navigation">
  <li class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">video_library
    <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">contact_support
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">mail
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can put i element in anchor element like this `<a><i class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">></i></a>`

Comment: @Eldar There is no `i` element in this library..see the original code.

Answer (score 2):

The text needs to be inside the link and the classes applied to those links...not the `li`.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<ul id="navigation">
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">video_library</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">contact_support</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">mail</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting icon inside `<a>`

```
 <li>video_library
        <a href="https://www.google.com"><i class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">video_library</i></a>
    </li>
```